# Early stop when validation loss satisfies certain criteria

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a neural net model in Keras. I want to monitor the validation loss and stop the training when certain condition is attained.

I know I can use `EarlyStopping` to stop the training when there is no improvement in training for a given number of `patience` rounds.

I want to something different. I want to stop the training when the `val_loss` is going above a value say `x` after `n` rounds.

To make things clear, Let's say `x` in `0.5` and `n` is `50`. I want to stop the model's training only if the `epoch` number is greater than `50` and `val_loss` is above `0.5`.

How can I do this in Keras.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own callback by inheriting from the Keras `EarlyStopping` callback and overriding it with your own logic:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping # use as base class

class MyCallBack(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, threshold, min_epochs, **kwargs):
        super(MyCallBack, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.threshold = threshold # threshold for validation loss
        self.min_epochs = min_epochs # min number of epochs to run

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if current is None:
            warnings.warn(
                'Early stopping conditioned on metric `%s` '
                'which is not available. Available metrics are: %s' %
                (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
            )
            return

        # implement your own logic here
        if (epoch >= self.min_epochs) & (current >= self.threshold):
            self.stopped_epoch = epoch
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

Small example to illustrate that it should work:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data
features = np.random.rand(100, 5)
labels = np.random.rand(100, 1)

validation_feat = np.random.rand(100, 5)
validation_labels = np.random.rand(100, 1)

# Define a simple model
input_layer = Input((5, ))
dense_layer = Dense(10)(input_layer)
output_layer = Dense(1)(dense_layer)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

# Fit with custom callback
callbacks = [MyCallBack(threshold=0.001, min_epochs=10, verbose=1)] 
model.fit(features, labels, validation_data=(validation_feat, validation_labels), callbacks=callbacks, epochs=100)
```

Comment: Nice one. I tried implementing this myself. I was getting some errors. I will refer this